# Handsontable - getSelected not working

Tags: javascript, excel, getselection, handsontable

I'm using handsontable to create some excel-like spreadsheets and I need to retrieve the data selected by the user to create a chart using gRaphael. But when I try to even alert the data selection parameters using this code:

```
var ht = $('#dataTable0').data('handsontable');
var sel = ht.getSelected();
alert(sel[0]);
```

I get 'undefined' written in the alert window. Can someone tell me how to fix this code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is obsolete, which may be the reason it doesn't work as intended.
The recommended way if you are using the latest version 0.9.7 is:

```
$('div#example1').handsontable(options);

//get the instance using jQuery wrapper
var ht = $('#example1').handsontable('getInstance');

//Return index of the currently selected cells as an array [startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol]
var sel = ht.getSelected();

//'alert' the index of the starting row of the selection
alert(sel[0]);
```

If you are using an older version I suggest downloading the latest version.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @polras, you can also add:

```
outsideClickDeselects: false
```

to handsonetable options

Comment: I just realized that my code actually worked fine, the thing was that this code (function) was called when I clicked on a link, and that caused the selection in the table to get 'deselected' which resulted with getting 'undefined' alert message. Sorry I bothered you for nothing. xD

Comment: same situation here. 
i added **outsideClickDeselects: false** to handsonetable options.
put this snippet for further reference

Comment: outsideClickDeselects: false saved me !

Answer (score 0):

first you need select rows Using ht.selectRows(start, end) or ht.selectAll(),
then when you call ht.getSelected() it will return array describes your selection (rows, cells)
[image]

finally you can call ht.getData(...ht.getSelected()[0]) this will pass the array of info returned from getSelected as arguments to getData function and will return array of data selected
[image]

*note: there are many scenarios in selection eg: you can select first to third rows and only first and last cell that's why getSelected return the array of 4 numbers and we pass that array to ht.getData.*